# Unable to assign types because Postgresql wrapped results in table name

Tags: angular, typescript, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I created a table in PostgreSQL using knex:

```
await knex.schema
    .withSchema('public')
    .createTable('question', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.text('title').notNullable().index();
        table.text('description').notNullable();
    })
```

Question Table:

```
| id | title | description |
| -- | ----- | ----------- |
| 0  | abc   | hello world |
| 1  | def   | Sleep World |
| 2  | ghi   | dream world |
```

Question model:

```
export interface Question {
    title: string;
    desciption: string;
}
```

Using Objection JS I created a query to get the questions:

```
getQuestions() {
    return Question.query().select('title', 'description');
}
```

Then, I try to assign `Question[]` type to the result:

```
const q: Question[] = await getQuestions();
```

The error says that I cannot assign the type because:

```
Type 'Model' is missing the following properties from type 'Question': title, desciption
```

When I print out the output (without assigning type), the results were wrapped in the table name:

```
[
  Question { title: 'abc', description: 'hello world' },
  Question { title: 'def', description: 'Sleep World' },
  Question { title: 'ghi', description: 'dream world' },
]
```

Why is the results wrapped in table name? I heard that they were normal, but it never happened to other nearly identical code.

Why can't I assign types to the results?

Answer (score 0):

`getQuestions` function returns Promise not the actual objects. try `const q: Question[] = await getQuestions();`

Comment: It was a typo. My bad.